# List records with over lapping date ranges in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have list of past experience records of employees in a table with columns

```
Registration_No,Join_Date,Resgn_Date
```

[image]

I am in need to list out the `Registration_No` where a date is over lapping.

The yellow blocks define that there is a over lap.

Is there any oracle functions which i could use ?

Sample Data Below:

```
CREATE table A (REGISTRATION_NO number,JOIN_DATE date,RESG_DATE date);

INSERT INTO A values(100,'1-JAN-93','30-DEC-93');
INSERT INTO A values(100,'1-MAY-93','20-MAY-93');
INSERT INTO A values(101,'1-DEC-93','1-NOV-95');
INSERT INTO A values(102,'1-JAN-96','30-MAY-96');
INSERT INTO A values(102,'5-MAY-96','20-DEC-96');
```

Comment: You could make use of this overlap function : https://github.com/kaushikjnayak/SQL_PLSQL/blob/master/Date_overlap.sql.

Comment: You could do this with a self join. If you post some sample data I can copy and paste, I'll put together an example.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson sample data added

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.Registration_No = t.Registration_No and
                    t2.Resgn_Date > t.join_date and
                    t2.join_date < t.resgn_date
             );
```

Comment: i tested it out, and i don't get the desired output

Comment: @HudhaifaYoosuf it may not give you expected output, but definitely give you understanding or way to continue.

Comment: @Ravi yes, it does

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.reg_number,t.JOIN_DATE,resign_date
from registration t
where exists (select 1
              from registration t2
              where t2.reg_number = t.reg_number and
                    t2.resign_date > t.join_date and
                    t2.join_date < t.resign_date
                    and t2.rowid<>t.rowid
             )
             order by reg_number,JOIN_DATE;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join or inner join on same table.

```
select 
   t1.Registration_No
from 
   t t1 inner join t t2 on 
  (t1.Registration_No = t2.Registration_No) and 
  ((t1.Resgn_Date - 1) =t2.join_date);
```

Comment: Please format your code and add some comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using your original data:

```
select a1.registration_no, a1.join_date, a1.resg_date as resg_date1
     , a2.resg_date as resg_date2
from   a a1
       join a a2
            on   a2.registration_no = a1.registration_no
            and  a2.resg_date > a1.join_date
            and  a2.resg_date < a1.resg_date;

REGISTRATION_NO JOIN_DATE   RESG_DATE1  RESG_DATE2
--------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
           7673 25/08/2001  31/12/2001  26/08/2001
          24939 28/01/1998  05/03/2003  29/01/1998
```

You could refine this some more to include join dates that fall between an existing join and resignation date.